# Search column for specific text and display any/all rows that contain a match

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

Here is the situation I am in…

Worksheet 1 has about seven columns the first column is the Patch identification the 5th column contains a list of different operating systems that need to have that patch.

In the second worksheet I want to create a formula that will go through row by row through the first worksheet and list the first, second and fourth cells for all rows that finds the target operating system in the fifth column.

Let me know if that was unclear?

Answer (score 0):

1. On Worksheet 1 make sure you set column headers with no duplicates.
2. Copy the column headers of the columns that you need to first row on Worksheet 2.
3. Lets say you copy 4 columns names, then on cell E1 you write the 5th column header from worksheet 1, and on cell E2 you write the Operating System name
4. make sure you're on worksheet 2.
5. go to Data> Filter> Advanced Filter.
6. Select Copy to another location
7. on List range: select the table from Worksheet 1 (eg: A1:G100)
8. on Criteria range: select cells E1:E2 from Worksheet 2
9. On Copy To: select column names from worksheet 2 (EG: A1:D1)
10. Click OK

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there may be some detail missing from @Alin I's description but assuming also that the OS details are one per cell then a pivot table should work:

[image: SO17108420 example]

Above is Tabular Form and without any totalling.